# Why spring.io generate pom without version?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-initializr

I'm new to springboot and using spring.io to create project in order to create microservices.

When creating a project using spring.io website, a pom is created with all the relevant
dependencies but versions are not added.
Should I add the versions myself looking the maven repository jar (all jars include
versions on them)?

Comment: No you shoildn't. The versions are managed by the parent.

Comment: Who is the parent? can I see it? I just want to make sure auto upgrade won't happened.

Comment: The thing defined by the `parent` tag in your pom. I strongly suggest you read on how maven works as you seem to be lacking in that area.

Comment: got you, org.springframework.boot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All dependencies (and configurations) are managed by Spring Boot. The parent of the project you generated with [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) has the parent set to [spring-boot-starter-parent](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.5.2/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.5.2.pom):

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

The parent of [spring-boot-starter-parent](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.5.2/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.5.2.pom) is [spring-boot-dependencies](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.5.2/spring-boot-dependencies-2.5.2.pom) which defines all dependency versions.

Therefore you don't need to specify any versions of the starter dependencies or their dependencies manually.

Please take a look at [The Spring Boot Starter Parent on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-starter-parent) for a quick overview.